# Код работает но не по заданию из Яндекс Практикума, помогите разобраться, что я делаю не так?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Нужно написать код по заданию, вроде как всё сделал но выдает ошибку "код работает, но сделал что то лишнее или что то не так"
Задание вот:

**Напишите функцию what_weather() (англ. «какая погода?»), которую затем будете использовать в коде Анфисы:**

1. Выполните HTTP-запрос, поместив вызов функции get() внутрь блока try.
2. Значения URL и параметров получите из функций make_url() (в неё нужно передать нужный город как аргумент city) и make_parameters().
3. При «выбрасывании» исключения типа requests.ConnectionError (от англ. «ошибка соединения») — функция what_weather() должна возвращать сообщение об ошибке '<сетевая ошибка>'.
4. Если код HTTP-ответа равен 200 (всё хорошо), верните из функции текст ответа. В противном случае функция должна вернуть строку '<ошибка на сервере погоды>'.

Скрин ошибки:

[image: Скриншот]

Сам код вот:

```
import requests


cities = [
    'Омск',
    'Калининград',
    'Челябинск',
    'Владивосток',
    'Красноярск',
    'Москва',
    'Екатеринбург'
]


def make_url(city):
    # в URL задаём город, в котором узнаем погоду
    return f'http://wttr.in/{city}'


def make_parameters():
    params = {
        'format': 2,  # погода одной строкой
        'M': ''  # скорость ветра в "м/с"
    }
    return params


def what_weather(city):
    try:
        response = requests.get(make_url(city), params=make_parameters())
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response
        elif response.status_code != 200:
            return '<ошибка на сервере погоды>'
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return '<сетевая ошибка>'



print('Погода в городах:')
for city in cities:
    print(city, what_weather(city))
```

Comment: Ну посмотрите на результат, который ваша программа печатает. Совсем не то сделал.

Comment: Так вот именно я не понимаю в чем дело, вроде get получает и url и params но возвращает что то не то, не могу разобраться

Comment: Возвращает именно то, что написано в коде.

Comment: Тогда в чем проблема?

Comment: Я затронул только функции make_url(), make_parameters() и what_weather(), остальной код я не менял, в чем собственно проблема то?конкретнее

Comment: Подсказка: у `response` есть атрибут `status_code` - мб там еще что есть атрибут или метод какой-нибудь

Comment: Да есть, я уже справил, надо было написать return response.text

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

cities = [
    'Омск',
    'Калининград',
    'Челябинск',
    'Владивосток',
    'Красноярск',
    'Москва',
    'Екатеринбург'
]

def make_url(city):
    # в URL задаём город, в котором узнаем погоду
    return f'http://wttr.in/{city}'

def make_parameters():
    params = '0TMq&lang=ru'
    return params

def what_weather(city):
    try:
        r = requests.get(make_url(city), params=make_parameters())
        r.encoding = 'utf-8'   
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return r.text
        else:
            return '<ошибка на сервере погоды>'
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return '<сетевая ошибка>'


print('Погода в городах:')
for city in cities:
    print(what_weather(city))
```

Список доступных параметров сервера погоды можно посмотреть здесь: https://wttr.in/:help

Comment: params = '0TMq&lang=ru как понять это?

Comment: Список доступных параметров сервера погоды можно посмотреть здесь: https://wttr.in/:help
 Смотрим наши опции:
 ?0       # только текущая погода
 ?T       # отключить терминальные последовательности (без цветов)
 ?M       # показывать скорость ветра в м/с
 ?q       # без текста "Прогноз погоды"
 lang=ru  # русский язык
  
  Опции можно комбинировать:

  /Красноярск?0TMq
  /Москва?0TMq&lang=ru